# Why does slick not work within SweetAlert 2 popup content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js, sweetalert2

Why does slick not working within SweetAlert 2 modal content, what am i doing wrong, Html loads perfectly but slick plugin doesn't seem to work within modal.

I've tried adding my html code with class that i've specified in slick, in sweetalert 2 but is not working, then i've added the slick on my footer just to see if it works and its working, so within sweetAlert2 content is not working, screenshot below.

[image: Here is screenshot of slick inside sweetAlert 2 content]

Out of sweetAlert 2, in my footer works fine.

[image: Here is the screenshot of slick working fine out of sweetAlert 2]

```
  var $slider;
     $slider = $('.subscriptionOffers');
       $slider.slick({
         infinite: true,
         arrows: true,
         centerMode: true,
         centerPadding: '0%',
         initialSlide: 0,
         focusOnSelect: true,
         speed: 300,
         prevArrow:'<div class="prev"><img src="images/prev.png"></div>',
         nextArrow:'<div class="next"><img src="images/next.png"></div>',
     });
     $('.subscribe-button-pc,.subscribe-button-mobile').on('click', function(){
       $slider.slick('slickGoTo', 0);

     });


  var sslider = '<div class="subscriptionOffers">';
  sslider += '<div style="text-align: center;"><h6 style="font-weight: 900; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 900;">Package 1</h6>';
  sslider += '<p><div class="popUpPrice">$30</div><label class="popUpReeC">/monthly</label></p>';
  sslider += '<p class="popUpDesc"></p>';
  sslider += '</div><div style="text-align: center;"><h6 style="font-weight: 900; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 900;">Package 2</h6>';
  sslider += '<p><div class="popUpPrice">$60</div><label class="popUpReeC">/3 months</label></p>';
  sslider += '<p class="popUpDesc"></p>';
  sslider += '</div><div style="text-align: center;"><h6 style="font-weight: 900; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 900;">Package 3</h6>';
  sslider += '<p><div class="popUpPrice">$250</div><label class="popUpReeC">/yearly</label></p>';
  sslider += '<p class="popUpDesc"></p>';
  sslider += '</div>';
  sslider += '<input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">';



$('.subscribe-button-pc,.subscribe-button-mobile').on('click', function(){
    const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
        customClass: {
          confirmButton: 'primary-btn btn userSearchFollowBtn',
        },
        buttonsStyling: false,
        showCloseButton: true
      })
      swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
        html: "" + sslider + "",
        confirmButtonText: 'Next step',
        reverseButtons: true
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {

        }
      })
});
```

Comment: Anyone any suggestions what should i do?

Comment: Saying it's "not working" doesn't tell us anything specific about the problem. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @user7290573 there is no error, i’ve tried loading slick first then sweetalert2 vice versa and still not loading as i show on the first screenshot, but when i place slider anywhere else on my html it loads and it works as shown on screenshot 2

Comment: @user7290573 any help?

Comment: Without seeing the full source code and there being no errors, it's pretty difficult to offer any help I'm afraid. Is your site visible online anywhere I can take a look?